# Hermite functions and integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, wavelets, spherical-harmonics

Let
$$h_n(x)=(-1)^n\gamma_ne^{x^2/2} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$
where $\gamma_n=\pi^{-1/4}2^{-n/2}(n!)^{-1/2}$ be a Hermite function.

Consider 
$$k_n(x,y)=\frac{h_{n+1}(x)h_n(y)-h_{n+1}(y)h_n(x)}{y-x}$$
such that there exists a positive constant $\Gamma$ such that for any $n$ and for all $x$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-1}(k_n(x,y))^2dy< \frac{2\Gamma^2}{n+1}, \quad \int_{1}^{\infty}(k_n(x,y))^2dy< \frac{2\Gamma^2}{n+1}$$
I am wondering if one can tell something about constant $\Gamma$, i.e. how small it can be?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: +1 I guess your question is how small $\Gamma^2$ could be. Could you please provide some context to your question too, if possible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. How small it can be. I wanted to use Uspensky result  http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1968401?uid=3739448&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=3737720&uid=4&sid=56223069203

Comment: for the prolate spheroidal function instead of f(x) in the Uspensky theorem.

Comment: Your $k_n(x,y)$ looks awfully like the Christoffel-Darboux expression for the Hermite polynomials...